# How do I save images properly in Magento?

Tags: image, rwd, magento-1.9

I want to show a image in the footer. I saved the image on my own PC. This is how I tried it: `<img alt=" Logo" src="C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\media\images\Logo.png" height="16" width="16" />`

All I get is a white 16x16 Block

Comment: I recommend to learn HTML, before learning PHP, before learning Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the foot is pulling from a static block/cms page use

```
<img alt=" Logo" src="{{media url='images/Logo.png'}}" height="16" width="16" />
```

If your using a phtml file

```
<img alt=" Logo" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);?>/images/Logo.png'}}" height="16" width="16" />
```